# MongoDB Springboot Query annotation giving only first record

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, annotations, spring-data

Issue: @Query annotation giving only first result instead of Multiple expected , for Spring Boot and MongoDB.

Ideally, I am expecting 5 records based on the query , but it is giving me just 1 (the first valid response).

Here is the code in my repository:

```
@Query("{unixTimestamp : {$lt : ?0, $gt : ?1}}")
List<DataType> findAllByUnixTimeStampRange(long upperlimit, long lowerlimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the query work on MongoDB command-line ?

If no, then check your query, because this issue is not caused by the `@Query` annotation